# type mismatch; found : scala.collection.immutable.Stream[String] required: String in Play Scala?

Tags: json, scala, scala-collections, anorm

I am trying to display json data from database using scala/anorm of Play(2.2.x), If I give the following trial, I am getting the error like: `type mismatch; found : scala.collection.immutable.Stream[String] required: String`, but If I write like: sql().map(row => rowString).toString - is giving Stream type json data(i don't need it), so how can I get my normal json data for it ? Please help me and thank in advance.

contorller:

```
class Test extends Controller {
    def getTest = Action { 
    var sql: SqlQuery = SQL("select name::TEXT from test");
    def values: String =  DB.withConnection { implicit connection => 
    sql().map(row => row[String]("name"))//giving error: type mismatch; found : scala.collection.immutable.Stream[String] required: String
    }
    Ok(values)
    }
```

Comment: What you have there is a `Stream`, a lazy collection. The first element is evaluated, but any further elements aren't that's why you get the `?`. It signifies there's probably still data left. The `\` you see are escapes. Not sure off my head how to unescape.

Comment: @Reactormonk, thanks for your reply, but this is the only json object stored in my database(so no other data is available in database, i mean generally we have id, that I don't want to display), that I need to display on hitting the url on view page, is there any mistake in my query ? How can I remove those Stream/slashes/? in my json ?

Comment: do you have a json or a `Stream` of json?

Comment: @Reactormonk, I am getting json like: Stream("[{\"_testid\":{\"test0id\":\"123\"},{\"testtitle\":\"123\"}"}]", ?) . But my desired json like: [{"__testid":{"test0id":"123"},{"testtitle":"123"}}]. I need to remove slashes/Stream/? from my json format. I am not sure whether it is a Stream of json or not(because I am not aware of Stream json), but I believe I have and need to return normal json only. So, is there any chance to remove all those from my json ?

Comment: Where are you getting that from? Something's wrong here. `Stream("foo")` indicates you have `Stream[String]`, not `String`.

Comment: @Reactormonk, yes, prinltln(values) is giving like: Stream("foo"), in my controller class  for definition: values, which is pasted in question description too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105113/discussion-between-dhana-and-reactormonk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using Anorm for database access. As noted in the comments above, executing the Anorm query returns a `Stream` rather than just a value. When you map the value, it is again returning a `Stream` of `String` so that the results can be processed as a stream. This is very useful for large result sets where it makes more sense to process the stream incrementally and stream the result to the client. It looks like you are just getting started so you probably don't want to worry about that right now.

You can covert the result from a stream into a conventional list by simply using `toList`:

```
val resList = sql().map(row => row[String]("name")).toList
```

Now, you also need to unescape the string and return it as a JSON result. That can be done by using string interpolations. To do this, you just need to surround the `String` in a `StringContext` and call the `s` method with no arguments.

```
val newResList = resList.map(s => StringContext(s).s())
```

Finally, you should actually be converting the String into a PlayJson JsValue type so that your controller is actually returning the right type.

```
Json.parse(newResList.mkString("[",",","]")
```

The `mkString` method is used to convert the list into a valid JSON string. You will need to `import play.api.libs.json.Json` for this to work. Passing a `JsValue` to `Ok` ensures that the mime type of the response is set to "application/json".  You can learn more about using JSON with play [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJson). This will be important if you intend to build JSON services.

Putting it together, you get the following:

```
class Test extends Controller {
  def getTest = Action { 
    var sql: SqlQuery = SQL("select name::TEXT from test");
    def values: JsValue =  DB.withConnection { implicit connection => 
      val resList = sql().map(row => row[String]("name")).toList 
      val newResList = resList.map(s => StringContext(s).s())
      Json.parse(newResList.mkString("[",",","]")
  }
  Ok(values)
}
```

You could also use the following alternate structure to simplify and get rid of the rather sloppy `mkString` call.

```
class Test extends Controller {
  def getTest = Action { 
    var sql: SqlQuery = SQL("select name::TEXT from test");
    def values: JsValue =  DB.withConnection { implicit connection => 
      val resList = sql().map(row => row[String]("name")).toList 
      Json.toJson(resList.map(s => Json.parse(StringContext(s).s())))
  }
  Ok(values)
}
```

This parses each of the JSON strings in the list and then converts the list into `JsArray` again using the capabilities of Play's built in JSON library.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have tried above two solutions, but I am getting the same error for two solutions: type mismatch; found : play.api.libs.json.JsValue required: String (at lines: Json.parse(newResList.mkString("[",",","]")) for first solution and Json.toJson(resList.map(s => Json.parse(StringContext(s).s()))) for second solution, please let me know about it, what to change kindly ?

Comment: I updated above. The type for values needs to be JsValue instead of String. Give it a try now.

Comment: If I run the first solution, getting error: [JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('_' (code 95)): was expecting comma to separate ARRAY entries at [Source: java.io.StringReader@446705b0; line: 1, column: 7]]
and If I run the second solution, getting: [JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('_' (code 95)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at [Source: java.io.StringReader@6403f91a; line: 1, column: 6]] at the above same lines. Please let me know,

Comment: I am getting: JsonParseException: Unexpected character...even if I upload/store normal json in my database while fetching into my view page. Is there any way of doing this escaping all these ? otherwise what I have to do for fetching and displaying my json data on my view page(and if I upload/give normal json data only, it is giving/appending some Stream/slashes in my database on displaying). Please help me regarding this ? It would be helpful for me if we have discuss on chat ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The reason it is failing is because your JSON is invalid. At least what you have pasted above – [{"__testid":{"test0id":"123"},{"testtitle":"123"}}] will not parse correctly. A valid version of this would be something like [{"__testid":[{"test0id":"123"},{"testtitle":"123"}]}] You cannot have two objects separated by a comma without making them an array.  If this is intended to be another object with two properties, the the following would be correct – [{"__testid":{"test0id":"123","testtitle":"123"}}]

Comment: actually that json is working fine in MongoDB, but it is not accepting in Postgresql database, I think it may give security issues with Postgresql (like slashes, ?s and Stream types, etc)?

Comment: Mongo's JSON parser might be more forgiving than Play's or PostgreSQL's. The example above, in formal sense, isn't valid. Hope this was all helpful.